# Will this "SIM Free" Android phone for sale near Osaka (Japan) work in Europe and North America?

Tags: sim-unlocking, localization, compatibility, carriers, gsm

Will this "SIM Free" Android phone for sale near Osaka (Japan) work in Europe and North America?

Hello,

So my phone recently went temporarily out of order and then I saw this Asus ZenFone 3 for sale in a second hand shop near Osaka (Japan).

It says "Sim Free" I think but do you guys think it would work in Europe and North America as well?

Vesa

[image: Phone description]

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Backside]

Answer (score 1):

This is the JP/TW variant of ZenFone 3 Max - detailed specs [here](http://phonedb.net/index.php?m=device&id=10545&c=asus_zenfone_3_max_dual_sim_td-lte_tw_jp_zc520tl_16gb).

From the listed LTE bands, it's missing the crucial Band 20 (wide coverage) for [European countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LTE_networks_in_Europe) and main bands for major carriers in the [US](https://www.phonearena.com/news/Cheat-sheet-which-4G-LTE-bands-do-AT-T-Verizon-T-Mobile-and-Sprint-use-in-the-USA_id77933). You will likely get less-than-stellar LTE coverage out of the device as a result. 3G will still work and likely suffice for most use cases.

Comment: So if I am somewhere like in Saigon (Vietnam) where the ISP provides 4G LTE (I think), will it automatically switch to 3G if the phone cannot handle 4G LTE? Or will it not work at all?

Comment: By "cannot handle" I mean it will receive weak or no LTE signal - it will then fall back to 3G.